# Sapere vs conoscere in "I know a language"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, word-meaning, meaning, difference

What is the difference between "So l'italiano" and "Conosco l'italiano"? I've seen both used in sentences.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Conoscere" comes from Latin "cognōscō, cognōscis, cognōvī, cognitum, cognṓscere", knowing, being acquainted with, having learned about things, people, places.

"Sapere" is from Latin "sapiō, sapis, sapīvī, sapēre" and "săpĭo, săpis, sapii, săpĕre" which in late centuries replaced, with the same meaning, "sciō, scīs, scī́vī, scī́tum, scī́re": knowing facts, having acquired skills, being able to do something.

"Cognṓscere" has the Greek root "gnosis", "γνῶσις", a deep understanding of something based on intuition.

"Scī́re" is the root of "scientia", science, a knowledge that you acquire empirically, through study, experiments. "Săpĕre" is about learning something by "savouring" it, "tasting" it.

A somewhat useful source is [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/conoscere-finestra-di-approfondimento_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/), not very specific in this case though. [Here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/conoscere/) and [here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sapere2/) too.

You can say:

```
«Conosco Giovanni» --> I know Giovanni

«So di Giovanni» --> I know (something) about Giovanni
```

but not

```
«So Giovanni»
```

You can say:

```
«L'ho conosciuto ieri» --> I met *him* yesterday

«L'ho saputo ieri» --> I got to know *it* yesterday
```

You can say:

```
«Conosco l'italiano» --> I know Italian language and I am familiar with the language

«So l'italiano» --> I am able to speak Italian
```

You can say:

```
«Conosco Roma» --> I know Rome (implying I know Rome well)

«So di Roma» --> I know (something) about Rome
```

but not

```
«So Roma»
```

When the verb "to know" is augmented by a dependent clause, you generally use the verb "sapere":

```
«So farlo» --> I am able to do it, I know how to do it

«So che è qui» --> I know it is here

«Sai quand'è, dov'è, com'è, chi è, cos'è, qual è?» --> Do you know when, where, how, who, what, which that is?
```

But you can also say:

```
«So perché lo fai» --> I know why you do it
```

and

```
«Conosco il motivo per cui lo fai» --> I know the reason why you do it
```

You can say:

```
«So di che parlo» --> I know what I am talking about
```

and

```
«Conosco l'argomento di cui parlo» --> I know the topic I am talking about.
```

Note that in the last instances, the dependent clause augments the nouns "motivo" and "argomento", not the verb "conosco".

Comment: I couldn't ask for more. I finally understand the difference and was also introduced to the wonderful world of "Treccani". Mille grazie randomatiabuser!

Comment: Really thorough answer. I might add, facetiously, that changing just a vowel, “so de Roma” might yield a completely different sentence ;)

Comment: @Agos, I think you mean "so' de Roma" ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Conoscere: (1) Avere cognizione precisa dell'esistenza e dei caratteri di un qualsiasi aspetto della realtà - anche come risultato di studio o apprendimento; riconoscere, discernere; essere informato su qualcosa. (2) Avere rapporti di familiarità più o meno stretti con qualcuno per averlo già visto o incontrato; fare la conoscenza, anche carnale, di qualcuno; distinguere. (3) Ammettere, accettare.

Sapere: (1) Possedere conoscenze acquisite tramite lo studio, l'apprendimento, l'applicazione intellettuale; avere imparato a memoria ed essere in grado di ripeterla perfettamente; avere una conoscenza generica di qualcosa; essere dotti, sapienti, avere grande erudizione. (2) Possedere cognizioni pratiche acquisite mediante l'esercizio, la pratica, l'esperienza; essere astuto, scaltro, pronto all'inganno; conoscere per esperienza personale. (3) Essere a conoscenza, essere informati a proposito di qualcosa; venire a conoscenza di qualcosa, apprendere. (4) Avere consapevolezza dei motivi che determinano un fatto, un comportamento e simili. (6) Avere la capacità, l'abilità di fare qualcosa - usato in funzione servile. (7) In senso intransitivo, avere un certo sapore o odore.

Comment: Please consider adding an English translation since the question is in English.

Comment: Oltre a una sintesi in inglese, occorre aggiungere la fonte delle definizioni.

Comment: Apparently the sources are [this](http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/c/conoscere.aspx?query=conoscere) and [this](http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/c/conoscere.aspx?query=sapere).